# Tabela dinâmica array vindo vazio javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

É o seguinte galera tenho uma tabela dinâmica em javaScript onde inclui uma linha com alguns dados preenchidos pelo usuário, no método de adicionar a linha coloquei um array passando também os campos que estou mandando para a tabela mas quando vou ver os valores do array não aparece nada como se estivesse vazio segue o código.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> pedido </title>
        
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
         
           
    totals =0;
   //Função que adiciona linha na tabela
    function adiciona(){
      
        //Array para pegar o valores mandados para a tabela
        var itens = [];
        var prod = document.getElementById('cprod').value; 
        var qtd = document.getElementById('cquant').value; 
        itens.push(prod, qtd); 
        
       
        
        
        
    totals++
        tbl = document.getElementById("tabelaBanco");
 
        var novaLinha = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        var novaCelula;
 
        if(totals%2==0) cl = "#FFFFFF";
        else cl = "##FFFFFF";

        novaCelula = novaLinha.insertCell(0);
        novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;
        novaCelula.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cprod').value;
        totals;
 
        novaCelula = novaLinha.insertCell(1);
        novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;
        novaCelula.innerHTML =  document.getElementById('cquant').value;
      

         novaCelula2 = novaLinha.insertCell(2);
         novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;
        var btnEl = document.createElement('input');  
        btnEl.setAttribute('type', 'button'); 
        btnEl.setAttribute('class', 'btn'); 
        btnEl.onclick = function ()      {deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)};  
        btnEl.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');  
       novaCelula2.appendChild(btnEl);   
       
       
     
    }
    
    function deleteRow(i){
    document.getElementById('tabelaBanco').deleteRow(i)
}
//Função de teste para ver se esta pegando o array
function pedido(){
    alert(itens);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

    <table>
       
    <td>  Produto: <input type="text" name="produto" id="cprod" /> </td>  
        
      <td> Quantidade: <input type="number" name="quantidade" id="cquant" /> </td>
      <td> <input type='button' id='incluir' value='Incluir Produto' class="btn btn-primary" onclick='adiciona()'/> </td>
    </table>
    
     <table id='tabelaBanco' class="table table-hover" border='0' width='100%'>
    <thead>
        <tr style='background-color:#FBF6F7'>
            <td class="produto"><strong>Produto</strong></td>
            <td class="quantidade"><strong>Quantidade</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Excluir</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Linhas e colunas correspondente aos seus registros -->
    </tbody>
</table>
    
    <p> <input type='button' id='confirmar' value='Confirmar Pedido' class="btn btn-primary" onclick='pedido()'/> 
    
</body>
</html>
```

A unica coisa que quero é colocar os dados no array

Answer (score 1):

Você está declarando a variável `itens` dentro do escopo da função `adiciona()`.
Tente declará-la no escopo global, juntamente com a variável `totals`.

Comment: Cara vc n sabe como me ajudou agora que besteira

Comment: Ás ordens, amigo! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcá-la como melhor resposta para retirá-la da sessão de Perguntas Sem Resposta.